# Downloading NOAA AVHRR NDVI using R

Tags: r, ndvi, noaa

I am  using the [**gimms**](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/gimms) package to automatically download NDVI data from 1981-2013. The code is provided [here](https://metvurst.wordpress.com/2015/10/14/introducing-the-gimms-package-6/). The data is available [here](http://ecocast.arc.nasa.gov/data/pub/gimms/3g.v0/). However, after running it shows that data has been downloaded but nothing in the download folder.
What might be the problem?

```
## load 'gimms' package
library(gimms)

gimms_files <- updateInventory(sort = TRUE)

gimms_files[1:20]

## download entire gimms collection
downloadGimms(dsn = paste0(getwd(), "/data"))
```

Comment: this worked perfectly on R 3.2.3, OS X 10.11.3, gimms 0.5.1. Are you sure there's a `data` directory in `getwd()`?

Comment: Yes I have set a working directory in my R, the same version in windows 7

Comment: When you run `dwnl <- downloadGimms(gimms_files[1], dsn = "/data")`, what is the value (i.e., the console output) of `dwnl`? You should see the location of the downloaded files relative to your working directory in there. The output of `sessionInfo()` could also provide further information.

Comment: The folder into which they are downloaded as displayed in the console is empty, however I have added more arguments tom the input code and I have been able to download.

Comment: Any news on this matter? @PeterMMacharia